# Building a manual sandbox for malware analysis

Tags: reverse-engineering, sandbox, analysis, malware

I want to build a manual sandbox to analyze malwares on Windows systems. I  mean a manual environment, not something automated like Cuckoo Sandbox.

There are many tools and I selected some of them, but I can't really see if each of this tool is worth it or not. Can you say me what you think and if these tools are useful for my sandbox?

First I consider some of them are unavoidables like IDA, winDBG, Wireshark, npcap, an HTTP Proxy like Fiddler, the Sysinternals suite, Volatility, maybe Foremost.

Then there are others tools I never really tried but which seems to be interesting. About static analysis, I have spotted the following tools and I would like to have an eventual feedback about it : Log-MD (a tool which look at the system using advanced Windows audit policies), Cerbero Profiler, Pestudio, Unpacker (it seems it is an automated tool to unpack binaries, seems faster but I am bit skeptical but I'm not a RE specialist, if you know this tool...), oledump.py by Didier Stevens (to identify various elements like heuristic patterns, IP, strings)...

About dynamic analysis, I noted Hook Analyzer (statically analyze elements with heuristic patterns and allow you to hook applications), Malheur (detect "malicious behavior"), ViperMonkey (detect VBA macro in Microsoft Office documents and emulate their behavior.

Do you have any recommandations about my setup and tools I could have forgotten? I want to analyze classic malicious elements (PE, PDF, various scripts, Office documents, ...).

About malware evasion, is there a risk a malware refuse to be analyzed while detecting RE and analysis tools?

Finally should I use Internet in the sandbox? Most of malwares today use C&C server and I see that some sandboxes are built with simulators like iNetSim but since the connection is not real, will I lost some information?

Thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider the [SEE](https://github.com/F-Secure/see) framework to build your analysis platform.

Its plugins based design will allow you to integrate scanning tools in a pretty flexible manner.

Bear in mind that lots of malware inspect the execution environment and, if any RE tool will be spotted, will refuse to run.

For what concerns the Internet connection, it depends on how much information you want to gather. It is indeed true that lots of malware communicate with C&C nowadays, yet they must ensure their persistence on the target machine.

Therefore, the injection mechanism will still be executed even if Internet connection is absent. My 2 cents on the matter is to run without Internet by default and activate it only when necessary.

Comment: Actually I initially considered using [Malboxes](https://github.com/GoSecure/malboxes) which is built for manual sandboxing and which includes various RE/debugging tools. However I asked myself how to analyse without those noisy tools which can be easily spotted by a malware. I have just taken a look to SEE and it seems really effective to solve this problem and I really like the plugin system which permit many custom settings and a complete analysis. Thank's :)